# Finding density function of random variable $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability

> Suppose $X$ is continuous r.v with c.d.f
>
> $$ F(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - \left( \frac{2}{x} \right)^2 \; \; \; \;
>  \; \; x>2 \\ 0, \; \; \; \; \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
>
> Put $Y=X^2$. Please find density function of $Y$.

#### Attempt

By definition $f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) $. We know

$$ F_y(y) = P(Y \leq y ) = P(X^2 \leq y ) = P(X \leq \sqrt{y} )$$

And hence

$$ F_y(y) = \int\limits_2^{\sqrt{y}} 1 - \left( \frac{2}{x} \right)^2 = \sqrt{y} + \frac{4}{\sqrt{y}}- 4  $$

It follows that

$$ f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}} - \frac{4}{2 y^{2/3} } $$

But,

my answer key say $f_Y(y) = \frac{4}{y^2}$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what book is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were already given the CDF of $X$.  Integrating again is not necessary.  We simply write $$F_Y(y) = F_X(\sqrt{y}) = 1 - \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{y}}\right)^2 = 1 - \frac{4}{y}, \quad y > 4,$$ thus $$f_Y(y) = \frac{4}{y^2}$$ as claimed.

Comment: OK, but what is wrong with his aproach. Why doesn't it work. It should, doesn't it?

Comment: @ChristianF $$F_Y(y)=\int_2^{\sqrt y}f_X(x)dx\ne\int_2^{\sqrt y}F_X(x)dx$$

Comment: How you get $F_Y(y) = F_X(\sqrt{y}) $ ? We have $ P(Y\leq y)=P(|X|\leq \sqrt y)$ from Here how we get $P(|X|\leq \sqrt y)=F_X(\sqrt{y})$